# Output node ,left and right child at once in Java

Tags: java, binary-tree

I am implementing a lexicographical binary tree and I need the output to be

```
 curent node data ; left child data ; right child data
```

For example, if I have this input:

```
banana apple curtain pumpkin egg
```

Going through the binary tree I need the output to be:

```
banana ; apple ; curtain
apple ; -1 ; -1
curtain ; -1 ; pumpkin
pumpkin ; egg ; -1
egg ; -1 ; -1
```

"-1" will be output if the left or right or both left and right child is null.

Here is my attempt to do this:

```
 public void insert(String newData){
     root = insert2(newData, root);

  }

  public BTNode insert2(String s, BTNode n){
      if(n == null){
          return new BTNode(s);
      }

      if(s.compareTo(n.data) < 0){
          n.left = insert2(s, n.left);
          if(n.right!=null)
              System.out.println(n.data+" "+n.left.data+" "+n.right.data);
          else System.out.println(n.data+" "+n.left.data +" "+ -1);




      }else if(s.compareTo(n.data) > 0){
          n.right = insert2(s, n.right);
          if(n.left!=null)
              System.out.println(n.data+" "+n.left.data+" "+n.right.data);
          else System.out.println(n.data+" "+ -1 +" "+n.right.data);

      }
      return n;


  }
```

The output of my attempt is:

```
banana apple -1
banana apple curtain
curtain -1 pumpkin
banana apple curtain
pumpkin egg -1
curtain -1 pumpkin
banana apple curtain
```

Thank you.

Comment: Why are you printing upon insterting? The order is given for visiting.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you misunderstood the task: the printing needs to be done when you walk a fully constructed binary tree. Since you are trying to print while your tree is under construction, some data is not available to you at the time when you need it. In particular, you cannot print `"banana"` or `"curtain"` on the first line, because all you have at that point is `"apple"`.

To fix this, remove all `println` calls from the `insert2` method, implement

```
void printTree(BTNode node)
```

method, and call it after the tree construction is complete. `printTree` implementation is straightforward - you print a string with the layout of the current node and its two children, then traverse the left subtree, followed by its right subtree, if any.